# What causes azure-hosted hangfire jobs to behave like this?

Tags: azure, hangfire

[image: Recurring job schedule]

I have been having trouble for a while with two recurring jobs (the ones at the top of this list) that don't get run even though they are scheduled.

I can trigger them just fine, and they get rescheduled, but when the schedule time comes around they don't run, and the "Next Execution" time just slips into the past.

Now there are a bunch of other jobs that are having the same problem. These are supposed to run hourly, but if they get past the schedule time they just don't run.

Visiting the dashboard makes no difference. The web app is always on. Hangfire will never run these jobs unless I trigger them manually. Jobs that AREN'T in this state still run just fine as scheduled every day or every hour.

What would cause this?

My hangfire instance (version 1.7.6) is in an Azure WebApp that is set to be always running. [image: See, it's always running!] It uses an Azure-sql database for its data store.

Here's my Bootstrapper.cs code:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Hosting;
using Hangfire;

namespace MyApi
{
    public class HangfireBootstrapper : IRegisteredObject
    {
        public static readonly HangfireBootstrapper Instance = new HangfireBootstrapper();

        private readonly object _lockObject = new object();
        private bool _started;

        private BackgroundJobServer _backgroundJobServer;

        private HangfireBootstrapper()
        {
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            lock (_lockObject)
            {
                if (_started) return;
                _started = true;

                HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(this);
                var jobOptions = new BackgroundJobServerOptions();
                jobOptions.ServerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("hangfire:servername");
                jobOptions.Queues = new[] {"k1"};

                GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                    .UseSqlServerStorage("Kdb");

                _backgroundJobServer = new BackgroundJobServer(jobOptions);
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            lock (_lockObject)
            {
                if (_backgroundJobServer != null)
                {
                    _backgroundJobServer.Dispose();
                }

                HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(this);
            }
        }

        void IRegisteredObject.Stop(bool immediate)
        {
            Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's code that is used to queue the majority of the jobs:

```
jobMgr.AddOrUpdate($"Script.{i1}.{name}", Job.FromExpression(() => HangfireJobs.ReplayQueue.EnqueueScript(scriptId, i1, null)),cronExpression);
```

Here's how my EnqueueScript method is defined:

```
    [Queue("k1")]
    public static void EnqueueScript(Guid scriptId, int env, PerformContext context)
    {
        try
        {
           ...
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a minimal setup to reproduce the issue? For example, can you give us some code sample and the settings that you have used in Azure to run Hangfire?

Comment: @dylanT, there are some possibilities. Can you determine from your logs if the process that the job runs isn't running longer than the next start time? For example if you're scheduled to kick-off Job_A @1:05 AM which executes whatever.process.it.kicks.off.for.A ..but... whatever.process.it.kicks.off.for.A isn't completed until 1:15 AM. Another possibility centers around processes built around  multitenancy. Do you know if your processes is intended for multitenancy? Are  you using multiple hangfire servers with the jobs named the same?

Comment: No the jobs don't run longer than the next start time. Most of them are done in under 1s. They are pretty quick. We are using two hangfire servers on this database, but they use different queues.

Comment: @TikluGanguly I would love to be able to repro the issue, but I don't know what causes this issue. If I gave my config chances are you would not experience the issue if you tried it.

Comment: Have you applied the `QueueAttribute` to your job classes/methods? Hangfire won't run jobs that are labeled as belonging to queues that aren't in your `Queues` setting. https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/configuring-queues.html

Comment: @TiesonT. Yes the queue attribute is applied to all jobs. Also I'd point out that most jobs are queuing and running fine. It's only when a job doesn't get run and slips into the past that it never gets run and never gets re-queued. Right now I have many jobs that are supposed to run hourly and haven't run for 10 days. They are all showing "10 days ago" as both "Next Execution" and "Last Execution".

Comment: @TiesonT. I added the method declaration for your info.

Comment: Hmm. Can't say that I've ever actually used the CRON feature of Hangfire. Is this .NET Core or .NET Framework?

Comment: .Net Framework @TiesonT.

Comment: What we are experiencing appears to be exactly the same as others are talking about in https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1459 don't know why this never showed up in any of my searching before?

Comment: @dylanT Does that seem to be the root cause, then? Probably worth writing up as an answer, if so.

Comment: I am awaiting an upgrade to Hangfire 1.7.8 before I commit my thoughts here. But yes I will post back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by upgrading Hangfire to version 1.7.8.

The Hangfire bug report is viewable at https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1459

It appears to have been introduced around version 1.7.4 (maybe earlier, but certainly by then) and fixed with version 1.7.8.